# ReactJS + Apollo Client - Get result without rendering

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I use ReactJS Typescript with Apollo Client.

I'm trying to know how to make a request to my server and store the result in a variable without generating a component?

I can do that :

```
<Query query={GET_AC}>
{({ loading, data }) => {
if (loading) return (<div>Loading</div>);
return (data.truc.map((ac) => <div>ac</div>));
</Query>
```

But I have to make a return with a component.

I would like to store the result in a variable of my component (and then make a live search system) without processing the result. How can I do that?

Like : `var result = query(maQuery); // In my component Class`

Thanks !

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you need to render the component where you want to store your variable in.  That way you can actually use it.  This will also allow you to fire off new queries from said component.

Comment: @larz Is it a good practice to create just one file for that?

Comment: IMO, best practice is to have one component (we will call it a container) that handles your data fetching, and then a presentation component that just handles displaying things and triggering stuff in your container.  Easier to test and easier to reuse.

Comment: Thank you Iarz !

Answer (score 1):

You can get data as prop by using Apollo HOC *graphql* or by using hook *useQuery* inside functional component.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Apollo's hooks

```
var result = useQuery(query)
```

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query

There's also another way which isn't very common, export your apollo client, and simply call the query function of it:

```
client.query({query: yourQuery})
```